# what happens when function doesnt explicitly return a value? can't figure out how the output of the code is coming

Tags: c, recursion, return-value, call

I came across a question in a test series, which when I solved manually according to my knowledge of C programming, should give an output which wasn't matching with any of the options given.

**My output = ' ++++ '**

**Question: Output of following c program is?**

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int f(int x) 
 {
     if(x==2){ return 2; } 
     else{ printf("+"); f(x-1); }
 }
 int main() 
 {
     int n = f(6); 
     printf("%d",n); 
     return 0; 
 }
```

**Options:**

1. '++++2' (correct option acc to answer key)
2. '+++++2'
3. '+++++'
4. '2'

**My logic:** Because in the end f(6) doesn't explicitly return anything [only f(2) returns the value 2 to f(3)], the output should only contain the 4 times '+' due to each call f(6), f(5), f(4) and f(3).

Below are some test code and their outputs screenshots i tried on online c compilers - 'codechef' and 'onlinegdb' - but i couldnt make sense of their outputs either. Please help!

codechef

[image: codechef]

onlinegdb 1

[image: onlinegdb 1]

onlinegdb 2

[image: onlinegdb 2]

Comment: If a function is declared to return a type, and ends without a `return` statement, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: The answer is 5. None and/or all of the above. Either that answer or the code is wrong. They're not both correct. The only reason you'd get a `2` back is because, by sheer chance, the stack contains a `2` on it, and that's if you compile in YOLO mode where you're not generating errors on this function not having a return value in every possible case.

Comment: That it does X consistently in compiler Y does not mean that's *defined behaviour*. It just means that compiler happens to work a certain way.

Comment: The code would be well defined if the `else` block had `return f(x-1);`

Comment: If the compiler does not generate something like: `error: non-void function does not return a value in all control paths`, then you need to use a different compiler or turn up the diagnostics.

Comment: The function execution never reaches the missing `return X` when originally called as `f(6)`

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes it does. After all the recursive calls return.

Comment: @Barmar yes yr right.

Comment: It's just a typo in the question.

Comment: It's undefined behaviour but (a) is not an unlikely answer in practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a function is defined to return a value and it doesn't, then attempting to use the returned value results in [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

This is documented in section 6.9.1p12 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> If the `}` that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.

This basically means that the result is not predictable and/or consistent.